# Cypress Auth0 tenant settings - what is "default audience"

Tags: cypress, auth0

I'm following the Auth0 application setup instructions for Cypress testing, as detailed [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/auth0-authentication#Auth0-Application-Setup).

I'm stuck on this step

> Next, click your Tenant icon (upper right avatar menu) to go to your Tenant Settings. On the General tab go to the API Authorization Settings.
>
> - Set "Default Audience" to the Audience URL for the Application you are testing (e.g. https://your-api-id.auth0.com/api/v2/)

What do I put for `your-api-id` (I'm not very familiar with Auth0 terminology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the URL that the Cypress test will use to call Auth0.

I find a good default is the Domain under the Application settings

- Navigate to the Applications menu
- Choose the application you are about to test
- Go to Setting sub-menu
- Copy the Domain setting from there

Example:

```
Domain:                          <my-domain>.us.auth0.com  
Tenant Default Audience: https://<my-domain>.us.auth0.com/api/v2/
```

where `<my-domain>` is the domain assigned during application setup.